# ggplot geom_bar not "stacked" or re-ordered

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to do a few things to my plot. The code for the basic plot I have is the following:

```
d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Major.sectors, y = reorder(Obs, Obs, function(x)-length(x)), fill = Status)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Model_Name, ncol = 1) +
  coord_flip()
```

I am trying to order the bars such that the largest bars will be on one side and the lowest bars will be on the other. I would like to stack them according to the "Status" variable also.

I think my problem comes about when I try to use `reorder(Obs, Obs, function(x)-length(x))` I am trying to `reorder()` all of the observations (inclusive of Status = 1 and Status = 0) when I should maybe `group_by` the `Model_Name` and `Major.sectors` then compute the total observations and then `reorder()` the data, such that the data is reordered on the total observation for each sector and model.

Secondly, the results do not make 100% sense. Looking at the plot for `3 Year`, `Publishing, printing`.

```
d %>% 
  filter(Model_Name == "3 Year" & Major.sectors == "Publishing, printing")
```

I get:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Status Model_Name Major.sectors          Obs
  <fct>  <chr>      <chr>                <int>
1 0      3 Year     Publishing, printing   422
2 1      3 Year     Publishing, printing    74
```

When looking at the plot for that year, the "blue" or the `Status = 1` color takes up approx 75% of the bar plot space but `74/422 = 0.175`.

I think the problem is again in regards to the `reorder()` function.

Data:

```
d <- structure(list(Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    Model_Name = c("1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", 
    "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", 
    "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "2 Year", 
    "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
    "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
    "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", 
    "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", 
    "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", 
    "3 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
    "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
    "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "1 Year", 
    "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", 
    "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", 
    "1 Year", "1 Year", "1 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
    "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
    "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
    "2 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", 
    "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", 
    "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "3 Year", "4 Year", 
    "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
    "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
    "4 Year", "4 Year"), Major.sectors = c("Chemicals, rubber, plastics, non-metallic products", 
    "Construction", "Education, Health", "Food, beverages, tobacco", 
    "Gas, Water, Electricity", "Hotels & restaurants", "Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling", 
    "Metals & metal products", "Other services", "Post & telecommunications", 
    "Primary sector", "Publishing, printing", "Textiles, wearing apparel, leather", 
    "Transport", "Wholesale & retail trade", "Wood, cork, paper", 
    "Chemicals, rubber, plastics, non-metallic products", "Construction", 
    "Education, Health", "Food, beverages, tobacco", "Gas, Water, Electricity", 
    "Hotels & restaurants", "Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling", 
    "Metals & metal products", "Other services", "Post & telecommunications", 
    "Primary sector", "Publishing, printing", "Textiles, wearing apparel, leather", 
    "Transport", "Wholesale & retail trade", "Wood, cork, paper", 
    "Chemicals, rubber, plastics, non-metallic products", "Construction", 
    "Education, Health", "Food, beverages, tobacco", "Gas, Water, Electricity", 
    "Hotels & restaurants", "Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling", 
    "Metals & metal products", "Other services", "Post & telecommunications", 
    "Primary sector", "Publishing, printing", "Textiles, wearing apparel, leather", 
    "Transport", "Wholesale & retail trade", "Wood, cork, paper", 
    "Chemicals, rubber, plastics, non-metallic products", "Construction", 
    "Education, Health", "Food, beverages, tobacco", "Gas, Water, Electricity", 
    "Hotels & restaurants", "Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling", 
    "Metals & metal products", "Other services", "Post & telecommunications", 
    "Primary sector", "Publishing, printing", "Textiles, wearing apparel, leather", 
    "Transport", "Wholesale & retail trade", "Wood, cork, paper", 
    "Chemicals, rubber, plastics, non-metallic products", "Construction", 
    "Education, Health", "Food, beverages, tobacco", "Gas, Water, Electricity", 
    "Hotels & restaurants", "Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling", 
    "Metals & metal products", "Other services", "Post & telecommunications", 
    "Primary sector", "Publishing, printing", "Textiles, wearing apparel, leather", 
    "Transport", "Wholesale & retail trade", "Wood, cork, paper", 
    "Chemicals, rubber, plastics, non-metallic products", "Construction", 
    "Education, Health", "Food, beverages, tobacco", "Gas, Water, Electricity", 
    "Hotels & restaurants", "Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling", 
    "Metals & metal products", "Other services", "Post & telecommunications", 
    "Primary sector", "Publishing, printing", "Textiles, wearing apparel, leather", 
    "Transport", "Wholesale & retail trade", "Wood, cork, paper", 
    "Chemicals, rubber, plastics, non-metallic products", "Construction", 
    "Education, Health", "Food, beverages, tobacco", "Gas, Water, Electricity", 
    "Hotels & restaurants", "Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling", 
    "Metals & metal products", "Other services", "Post & telecommunications", 
    "Primary sector", "Publishing, printing", "Textiles, wearing apparel, leather", 
    "Transport", "Wholesale & retail trade", "Wood, cork, paper", 
    "Chemicals, rubber, plastics, non-metallic products", "Construction", 
    "Education, Health", "Food, beverages, tobacco", "Hotels & restaurants", 
    "Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling", "Metals & metal products", 
    "Other services", "Post & telecommunications", "Primary sector", 
    "Publishing, printing", "Textiles, wearing apparel, leather", 
    "Transport", "Wholesale & retail trade", "Wood, cork, paper"
    ), Obs = c(471L, 3594L, 1029L, 657L, 620L, 1648L, 981L, 718L, 
    5270L, 124L, 959L, 422L, 288L, 1375L, 6221L, 217L, 449L, 
    3492L, 988L, 628L, 586L, 1554L, 961L, 706L, 5127L, 105L, 
    918L, 425L, 269L, 1262L, 5966L, 218L, 443L, 3336L, 922L, 
    599L, 592L, 1454L, 913L, 666L, 4830L, 89L, 870L, 422L, 260L, 
    1182L, 5673L, 213L, 438L, 3371L, 886L, 584L, 527L, 1377L, 
    887L, 684L, 4609L, 91L, 844L, 415L, 250L, 1114L, 5463L, 207L, 
    118L, 1080L, 49L, 98L, 16L, 139L, 210L, 161L, 521L, 19L, 
    68L, 83L, 69L, 145L, 762L, 44L, 119L, 1109L, 48L, 98L, 14L, 
    134L, 220L, 166L, 508L, 14L, 65L, 79L, 68L, 144L, 771L, 42L, 
    113L, 1094L, 41L, 91L, 12L, 127L, 201L, 147L, 476L, 12L, 
    66L, 74L, 71L, 131L, 733L, 43L, 111L, 1027L, 39L, 87L, 117L, 
    191L, 147L, 434L, 13L, 66L, 70L, 67L, 128L, 681L, 41L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -127L))
```

Comment: Why are you trying to reorder the y axis? Can you try something like this ? `ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Major.sectors, Obs), y = Obs, fill = Status))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the `reorder` function on the wrong variable which convert your "Obs" values in a factor format.

Instead try this:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x = reorder(Major.sectors, Obs), y = Obs, fill = Status))+
  geom_col()+
  facet_wrap(~Model_Name, ncol = 1)+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]